# Venv fails in CentOS, ensurepip missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, centos, python-venv

Im trying to install a `venv` in `python3` (on `CentOS`). However i get the following error:

> Error: Command '['/home/cleared/Develop/test/venv/bin/python3', '-Im',
>   'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit
>   status 1.

I guess there is some problem with my `ensurepip`...

Running `python3 -m ensurepip` results in

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/_bundled/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl'

Looking in the `/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/_bundled/` I find `pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl` and `setuptools-40.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`, however no `pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Running `pip3 --version` gives

> pip 20.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python
>   3.6)

Why is it looking for pip-**9.0.3**-py2.py3-none-any.whl when I'm running pip **20.0.1**, and why to i have pip-**18.1**-py2.py3-none-any.whl? And how to I fix this?

Comment: I don't even have a _bundled directory. Which rpm provides it ? yum whatprovides doesn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These versions are harcoded at the beginning of `./lib/python3.8/ensurepip/__init__.py`. You can edit this file with the correct ones.

Regarding the reason of this corruption, I can only guess. I would bet on a problem during the installtion of this interpreter.

Comment: Thank you, I changed `_PIP_VERSION = "9.0.3"` to `_PIP_VERSION = "18.1"` in `/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/__init__.py` and then it worked. I am not 100% comfortable changing modules like that, but I see no other way. I hav no idea where the issue comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a clean reinstall of Python (and maybe some of its dependencies as well) with your operating system's package manager (yum?).