# Python package creation on Windows fails with „ … python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.“

Tags: python, arcgis, ensurepip

I’m working on Windows with ArcGIS Pro and Python and I have a copied conda env from ArcGIS Pro.
If I try to build a package the following error is displayed:

```
ERROR Command '['C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\build-env-lljm30w\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

It worked before with an older ArcGIS Pro Version and I think I found the problem:

The .whl file in *Lib\ensurepip_bundled* is pip-**21.1.3**-py3-none-any.whl and not pip-**20.1.1-py2**.py3-none-any.whl

It works if I manually copy the „old“ .whl file (from a coworker with the older ArcGIS Pro Version - still trying to get the version details) in the directory before I start the build process.

Since this can’t be the solution, I’m still looking for one.
Anything I need to update? From what I understand the *_bundled* directory can’t be updated since it is already a part of the python version. But why does the (integrated) build version needs an older pip.whl?

Could someone please help me.

Python: 3.7.11
Arcgis Pro: 2.9.2
pip: 22.0.4
build: 0.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation: Upgrade ArcGIS Pro which subsequently upgraded the underlying python from 3.6 to 3.7.11. This tanked my ability to build virtual python environments on top of my ArcPro python. I had the same error message as you.

Your question helped me narrow the problem to the `ensurepip` part of the equation. I followed the accepted answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855477/venv-fails-in-centos-ensurepip-missing) where a similar problem was recorded. So, I had to update the `_PIP_VERSION` variable to match my `.whl` file; in my case, this was `21.1.3` to match the file `pip-21.1.3-py3-none-any.whl`.

But, additionally, we also have the `py2.py3` issue (which the OP of the other question did not). To fix this, I edited the last item of the last list in the `_PROJECTS` variable to become `"py3")` instead of `"py2.py3")`.

After I made these two changes, I was able to install a venv to my ArcGIS-based python interpreter.

So, lines 12-19 of my `__init__.py` for `ensurepip` now look like this:

```
_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION = "47.1.0"

_PIP_VERSION = "21.1.3"  # "20.1.1"

_PROJECTS = [
    ("setuptools", _SETUPTOOLS_VERSION, "py3"),
    ("pip", _PIP_VERSION, "py3"),  # "py2.py3"),
]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks, it works. Still don't get why "does the (integrated) build version needs an older pip.whl?". But at least it works :)

Comment: Great! Not sure if you were trying to use virtual envs, but I've run into more ArcGIS python interpreter ~ ensurepip trouble since this original issue. I've [written something](https://github.com/cooperjaXC/windows_python_venv/commit/945802c86f8e4e77dd5e6e6d40e7fe3b347dec6a) to direct venvs to source from the ensurepip you have, not what it thinks you should have. Hope it's of help.